# Tried installing Ubuntu w/o CD/USB. Tried Unetbootin and no success on Win10.

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation

I lack a CD-Rom and a USB-stick, so I was trying to find an alternative way to install Ubuntu. I did found unebootin. I followed the instructions on it to the best of my ability. After I rebooted my computer, I got this screen: [http://imgur.com/uBgHGbJ](https://imgur.com/uBgHGbJ), which I expected to see; however, I got this error screen after clicking on the Unebootin option: [http://imgur.com/Ov1k4eE](https://imgur.com/Ov1k4eE).

I have a Windows 10 ASUS laptop, and not really sure what the issue is. I tried messing with the booting specs in the BIOS, but nothing ended up working at the end.

I looked at a similar thread and it mentioned something about legacy boot to solve his problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Windows and if your computer is powerful enough, you can install VirtualBox in Windows. In VirtualBox you can create a **virtual machine**, and can connect the Ubuntu iso file as a DVD disk, and boot from it and run a live session 'Try Ubuntu'.

If it looks good, you can stop the virtual machine and create a virtual disk. Start the virtual machine again and you can install Ubuntu to the virtual disk.

-o-

**Alternatives**

- Maybe you can borrow a USB stick, and make it into an Ubuntu boot drive and install Ubuntu from it to the internal drive of the computer.
- Or if you have a second (maybe old) hard disk drive, you can use that drive instead of a USB stick.
- Some computers (but far from all) can boot from the SD card slot, so if you have an SD card, you might be able to make it an Ubuntu boot drive.
- It is also possible to boot via the network, but it is not easy.

Can you do this **together with someone else**, who is also interested in trying Ubuntu? In this case there are more options, depending on the hardware that both of you have and can borrow. Maybe you can find a local [Linux user group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_user_group) or some other computer club.